# Mouse events - mousemove in javascript don't respond in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, mouseevent, mousemove

I have a problem with the mousemove event when i have 2 or more canvas elements.

I press the mouse button while the cursor is in the second canvas (v2) then I move the mouse cursor to the first canvas (v1) while still holding the mouse button and let go of the mouse button.
Afterwards when i try to press on the button and move it around in the first canvas (v1) - the event mousemove doesn't work (the index doesn't get index++).

I get a no entry sign when i try to move the mouse inside the first canvas.
it only happens when i try to do it from v2 to v1 but the other way around it works fine.
it only happens on IE9 and not any other web browser that i checked (chrome, FF, IE 10/11).

here is an example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
var index = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#v1").mousedown(function(){
    $("#v1").css("background-color","black");
  });
  $("#v1").mousemove(function(){
    index ++;
    $("#v1").css("background-color","red");
  });


  $("#v2").mousedown(function(){
    $("#v2").css("background-color","black");
  });
  $("#v2").mousemove(function(){
    index ++;
    $("#v2").css("background-color","red");
  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="v1"><canvas width="150" height="150" id="viewer"></canvas></div>
<br/>
<div id="v2"><canvas width="150" height="150" id="viewer2"></canvas></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this code is not understandable i can write something else that might be more helpful.